How to Solve for $AA^T$ Given $C = ABA^T$ with Symmetric Matrices $B$ and $C$?
I'm currently facing a challenge in solving for the matrix $AA^T$ given the equation $C = ABA^T$, where both $B$ and $C$ are known symmetric matrices. The matrix $A$ can be non-symmetric, which complicates the problem.
Problem Description:
I have successfully solved the case where $A$ is symmetric by computing $CB = ABAB = (AB)^2$, and then performing an Eigenvalue Decomposition (EVD) on $AB$. This approach only leaves me with a sign ambiguity. However, I'm struggling to find a solution for the more general case when $A$ is non-symmetric.
Background:
The context of the problem is related to signal processing, where $y = Hx$, and $x$ has a Gaussian distribution with covariance $C_x$. The covariance relation is given by $C_y = HC_xH^T$. My goal is to deduce $HH^T$ solely from the observed distribution of $y$ and the known distribution of $x$.

Assuming $B$ and $C$ are positive-definite, take the Cholesky decomposition of $B=L_BL_B^T$ and $C=L_CL_C^T$. Now we have
$$L_C L_C^T = AL_B L_B^T A^T = (AL_B)(AL_B)^T$$
Since the Cholesky decomposition is unique for positive-definite matrices, it must be that
Note that this doesn't imply $L_C=AL_B$, because $AL_B$ doesn't have to be lower triangular (otherwise, the equality would follow from uniqueness of Cholesky decomposition).
To find some solution, we can assume
$$L_C = AL_B$$
Meaning that
$$A = L_C L_B^{-1}$$
From here,
$$AA^T = L_C L_B^{-1} L_B^{-T} L_C^T = L_C (L_B^T L_B)^{-1} L_C^T $$
which doesn't seem to simplify further. Note that
$$ L_B^T L_B \quad{\color{red}\neq} \quad L_BL_B^T=B$$

Thank you for your response. I believe this at least proves that your results are correct when ( A ) is a lower triangular matrix, yes?

I think this almost solves my problem. For the true matrix $A$, I can express it as $L_C = AL_B U$, where $U$ is a unitary matrix. Thus, $A$ can be described as $L_C U L_B^{-1}$. This is sufficient for me since I know some additional properties of $A$ in my problem that help me formulate an optimization problem.
